# How can I show a div only when hovering a menu item or the div?

Tags: jquery, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

I have items contained in an unordered list.  I have hidden divs (using display:none;) outside of this list.  When you hover over a list item, I would like the div to appear.  It must also remain visible if you move your mouse from the list item to the div below it.

I am open to accomplish this through CSS, JavaScript/jQuery.  Also, my document is set to HTML5.

This is what I am currently working with.

```
<nav id="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="first-link parent" href="">First Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="second-link parent" href="">Second Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="third-link parent" href="">Third Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="fourth-link parent" href="">Fourth Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- #main-menu !-->
```

And beneath the nav, I have the content that I would like to display when hovering over the corresponding item.

```
        <div id="first-widget" class="widget-container">
            <h2>Sub Title</h2>              
            <p>Lorem Ipsum
            <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

        </div><!-- .first-widget !-->


<div id="second-widget" class="widget-container">
            <h2>Sub Title</h2>              
            <p>Lorem Ipsum
            <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

        </div><!-- .second-widget !-->

<div id="third-widget" class="widget-container">
            <h2>Sub Title</h2>              
            <p>Lorem Ipsum
            <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

        </div><!-- .third-widget !-->



<div id="fourth-widget" class="widget-container">
            <h2>Sub Title</h2>              
            <p>Lorem Ipsum
            <a href="#">Read More</a></p>

        </div><!-- .fourth-widget !-->

    </aside><!-- .hidden !-->
```

I feel like there should be an easy solution to this, but my attempts so far have fallen short.  The biggest problem is having the div show not only when hovering the menu item, but also when you move from the menu to the visible div.

Any advice is appreciate, thank you for taking the time to read this far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can wrap the widgets in a `div` and attach a `mouseleave` event to it. This solution also uses the `rel attibute` to store the widget `id`:  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/alpacalips/nDsR9/5/)

HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <nav id="main-menu">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="first-link parent" rel="first-widget" href="">First Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="second-link parent" rel="second-widget" href="">Second Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="third-link parent" rel="third-widget" href="">Third Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="fourth-link parent" rel="fourth-widget" href="">Fourth Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav><!-- #main-menu !-->

    <div id="first-widget" class="widget-container">
                <h2>Sub Title 1</h2>              
                <p>Lorem Ipsum
                <a href="#">Read More</a></p>
     </div><!-- .first-widget !-->
      ...
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#main-menu a').mouseover(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   var id = $this.attr('rel');
   var $currentWidget = $('#' + id);
   $currentWidget.show().siblings('.widget-container').hide();
});
$('#wrap').mouseleave(function() {
    $('.widget-container').hide();
});
```

Comment: Oh hey, heads-up- I improved the js a little.

Comment: Again, thanks so much.  One last question... Is there a way I could keep the initial menu item in the :hover state after I move the mouse over the .widget-container ?

Comment: @alpacalips, How can we make it work like a dropdown menu and show div like a submenu under that particular parent menu

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

Using [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) to bind the event, [`.index`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) and [`.eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to find which one to show/hide and the native JS methods for timeouts to let you hover the divs.

```
var timeout; // store a timeout here

$('#main-menu lia ').hover(function ()
{
    $('.widget-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).show();
}, function ()
{
    timeout = setTimeout(function ()
    {
        $('.widget-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).hide();
    }, 1000);
);

$('.widget-container').hover(function ()
{
    clearTimeout(timeout);
}, function ()
{
    timeout = setTimeout(function ()
    {
        $(this).hide();
    }, 1000);
});
```

Comment: Joe, thank you for the prompt response.  I added the following to my page, but the widgets are not appearing.

`<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#home-nav ul li a ').hover(function ()
{
    $('.widget-container').eq($(this).parent().index()).toggle();
});
}
</script>`

Comment: Joe, thank you so much for taking the time to help me out.  I am trying this out now and will let you know how it goes.